# Java Grade Calculator

Tags: java, string, while-loop, runtime-error

My objective is to have the user enter the name of a category, the grade of that category, and the weight of that category.

In theory, everything should work perfectly, except my first loop never ends.

This is the code I have so far:

```
package gradecalculator;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class GradeCalculator 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String categoryName = null;
        double categoryGrade;
        double categoryWorth;
        double Grade = 0;

        String[] nameArray = new String[10];
        double[] gradeArray = new double[10];
        double[] worthArray = new double[10];
        double[] categoryArray = new double[10];

        int c = 0;
        int c1 = 0;

        Scanner entry = new Scanner(System.in);

        while(!"Quit".equals(categoryName))
        {
            categoryName = entry.next();
            nameArray[c] = categoryName;

            categoryGrade = entry.nextDouble();
            gradeArray[c] = categoryGrade;

            categoryWorth = entry.nextDouble();
            worthArray[c] = categoryWorth;

            categoryArray[c] = finalCategory(categoryGrade, categoryWorth);

            c++;
        }

        while(c != 0)
        {
            System.out.printf("%S:\t%f%\tWorth: %f\n", nameArray[c1], gradeArray[c1], worthArray[c1]);
            c--;
            c1++;
        }

        while(c1 != 0)
        {
            Grade = Grade + categoryArray[c];
            c1--;
            c++;
        }
    }

    public static double finalCategory(double Grade, double Worth)
    {
        return (Grade * (Worth / 100));
    }
}
```

I believe that the problem has been narrowed down to:

```
while(!"Quit".equals(categoryName))
        {
            categoryName = entry.next();
            nameArray[c] = categoryName;

            categoryGrade = entry.nextDouble();
            gradeArray[c] = categoryGrade;

            categoryWorth = entry.nextDouble();
            worthArray[c] = categoryWorth;

            categoryArray[c] = finalCategory(categoryGrade, categoryWorth);

            c++;
        }
```

and more specifically:

```
while(!"Quit".equals(categoryName))
```

What I am trying to accomplish is that as soon as the user enters the `categoryName` and it turns out to be the word "Quit", the while loop will be terminated, and the program will move on. Obviously this isn't happening, so I would greatly appreciate any help to solve the problem.

Comment: try putting an `if(categoryName.equals("Quit")) break;` after you call each `.next()` and `.nextDouble()` and before you assign the value to the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the while-loop body continues execution even when `categoryName` is `"Quit"`. You can assign `entry.next()` to `categoryName` and do a `"Quit"` check all in the while-loop's condition:

```
while(!(categoryName = entry.next()).equals("Quit"))
{ ... }
```

This line would have to be removed (first line of while-loop body):

```
categoryName = entry.next();
```

There's also a problem in your format String:

```
"%S:\t%f%\tWorth: %f\n"
```

`%\t` will try to find a conversion for the tab character. If you want to print `%` literally, escape it with another `%`:

```
"%S:\t%f%%\tWorth: %f\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

You ask for `categoryName` before you take input for the other doubles. Your program is waiting for you to enter the next doubles even after you enter `"Quit"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see if the string the user entered was "quit" directly after they input their string. Just add the code below after categoryName = entry.next();

`if(categoryName.equalsIgnoreCase("quit"))
                break;`

This ignores the case that the user enters as well if that's what you want.